# Switch between Debug and Release configurations

Tags: build, clion

I have a CMake project with some targets.
When I'm loading this project to the CLion, CLion generates Run/Debug configuration for each target. It's ok. But when I change configurations from Debug to Release in CMake preferences:
[image: CMake preferences]
Configuration for each Run/Debug configuration doesn't change automatically:
[image: Run/Debug configurations]
So I have to change configuration to Release for each Run/Debug configuration manually. Is there any possibility to change configuration automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not such option. However, in 2016.3.2 we've added a possibility to have several (say Debug/Release) configurations at once. RC build is available, official release should be delivered most likely next week. The new behaviour is described in our [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/12/clion-2016-3-2-eap/).